# ¿Cómo ocultar y mostrar columnas en Datatables js?

Tags: javascript, datatables

Quiero mostrar y ocultar las columnas de una tabla, pero obtengo el siguiente error

> ReferenceError: table is not defined

Y mi código es el siguiente:

```
oTable = $('#pedidos-table').DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "oLanguage": {
      "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
      "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
      "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
      "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
      "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
      "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
      "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
      "sInfoPostFix": "",
      "sSearch": "",
      "sUrl": "",
      "sInfoThousands": ",",
      "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
      "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst": "Primero",
        "sLast": "Último",
        "sNext": "Siguiente",
        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
      }
    }
  });    
  var thead = [];
  var count = 0;
  $("#pedidos-table thead tr th").each(function() {
    thead.push($(this).text());
  });

  thead.forEach(function(dato) {
    $(".breadcrumb").append("<li class='breadcrumb-item' data-column='"+count+"'><a>"+dato+"</a></li>");
    count ++;
  });
  $(".breadcrumb-item").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the column API object
    var column = table.api().column( $(this).attr('data-column') );

    // Toggle the visibility
    column.visible( ! column.visible() );
  });
});
```

Comment: El error es auto explicatorio: `ReferenceError: **table is not defined**`, es decir, la variable `table` no está definida en ningún lado; deberías cambiarlo por `oTable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
// Get the column API object
    column = table.columns($(this).attr('data-column'));

    // Toggle the visibility
    column.visible( ! column.visible() );
```